# IronPython .NET launcher in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I've installed IronPython then installed Microsof Visual Studio I want to be able to step into C# code but the 'IronPython (.NET) launcher' is not in the Debug window (shown below) only the 2 shown:
[image]

According to Microsoft:
[image]

How can I add the IronPython (.NET) launcher?

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using? PTVS [dropped IronPython support with ~ VS2022](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/will-vs-2022-support-ironpython/1477532).